# Text that does look smooth

Tags: html, css

All my fonts on my website, is kinda squared, like this text on the website.

If you visit http://www.momondo.dk/ and watch that text, its kinda "sharp or smooth" how would i be able to get that on my own website?

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: Perhaps it's the font(s) they're using, I don't see any specific CSS on the texts doing what you describe. Could you speficiy which text part has that effect?

Comment: Did you try to use a google font instead ? I think the font you choosed is not made for web.

Comment: Text on "Fly" "Hotel" "Bil" and im using Google chrome. I used the same font, but its something else that makes it like that

Comment: please provide a JSfiddle (we need to see the code)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bpP3q/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its due to the font they are using:

This would be the CSS:

```
    h1 {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    }
```

Also, add this:

```
 .title h1 {
    color: #c6aefb;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px 30px 5px;
    }
```

**Edit:**

Add this code:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Now only add:

```
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
```

Comment: Don't forget to check that you have the legal permission to use this font too.

Comment: @DanielLisik how can I check that ?

Comment: google for it. I looked and it seems to be ok to use it: http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans

Comment: Sounds all set: https://www.google.de/search?q=open+sans&oq=open+sans&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1722j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Still not able to be as smooth as the website i linked, this is the same here